# Heatmap Colors on leaflet in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have created a heatmap on top of a city that I would like to color from red to green depending on density. if I leave color as 'red' or 'blue' it will create a color scale of that one color. Yet I cannot seem to figure out how to do a green to red.

I have tried both what I have here and also a palette option that doesn't seem to get anywhere. This current one shows up black.

Does anyone know how to get these colors to show?

```
leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite",
         options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE,minZoom=9)) %>%
    addPolygons(data=polys_dat,color= ~rainbow(n=50,start=0,end=.3), stroke = FALSE) %>%
    setMaxBounds(-0.715485, 51.252031, 0.514984, 51.745313) %>%
    setView(.1,51.5, zoom = 9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the palette function first and then use that in your `addPolygons` function. If we assume you have a field in your `polys_dat` function called `density` with your values then the following should work.

```
pal = colorNumeric(colorRamp(c('green', 'red')), polys_dat$density)

leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite",
         options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE,minZoom=9)) %>%
    addPolygons(data=polys_dat,color= ~pal(density), stroke = FALSE) %>%
    setMaxBounds(-0.715485, 51.252031, 0.514984, 51.745313) %>%
    setView(.1,51.5, zoom = 9)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the tilde?